# The required column was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation and [NotMapped] has not helped

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core-3.0, ef-core-3.0

I am using EF Core 3.0 to fetch data from a SQL Server stored procedure into my object model named `Recipient`. The `Recipient` model has a couple of properties defined, `EnvelopeId` and `Name`, that are not returned from the stored procedure. When I invoke the stored procedure using `FromSqlInterpolated`, I get the error message

> The required column 'EnvelopeId1' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

From what I have read in the EF Core documentation, I should be able to add a `[NotMapped]` attribute to those properties and EF Core should be able to ignore them while reading from or writing to the database, right? Unfortunately, that isn't working for me and I am getting the above error.

If I add the two columns in the stored procedure and remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute in my object model, everything works fine. This proves that my other column/property names match up correctly and there isn't a typo anywhere.

I have seen suggestions of using `DbQuery` instead of `DbSet`, but that is being deprecated so I don't want to use that. I have seen suggestions of using two different object models, one with the properties exactly matching the stored procedure result set, but that just leads to lots of extra models. What am I doing wrong here?

My object model:

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace MyNamespace.Models
{
    public class Recipient
    {
        [Key]
        public long RecipientId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public Guid? EnvelopeId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public int RoutingOrder { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }

        public Recipient() { }
    }
}
```

My DB context:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyNamespace.Models;

namespace MyNamespace.Data
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<Recipient> Recipient { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Envelope> Envelope { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Template> Template { get; set; }

        public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)   
        { }
    }
}
```

My failing code:

```cs
FormattableString sql = $"EXEC dbo.MyStoredProcedure @Param1={param1}, @Param2={param2}";
var result = await MyDbContext.Recipient.FromSqlInterpolated(sql).ToListAsync();
```

**Edit #1 ...**

The `Envelope` object model:

```cs
public class Envelope
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EnvelopeId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusPollDate { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; }

    public Envelope() {
        Recipients = new List<Recipient>();
        StatusPollDate = DateTime.Parse("1753-01-01");
    }
}
```

The stored procedure result set schema:

```sql
[RecipientId] bigint,
[Type] varchar(20),
[UserId] varchar(50),
[Email] varchar(100),
[RoleName] varchar(100),
[RoutingOrder] int,
[Status] varchar(13),
[StatusDate] datetime
```

After reading some of the answers and comments, I have realized that a shadow property is being created by EF because it recognizes that `Recipient` is a child of the `Envelope` object. To be honest, I really *should* include the `EnvelopeId` in the result set (and remove `[NotMapped]`) to appease EF Core. The only reason I wasn't returning `EnvelopeId` in the result set of the stored procedure was because I had passed it in as an input parameter to begin with, and thought it was wasting network resources to pass something in and then get it back in each result set record.

Now I don't know where `EnvelopeId1` came from, but that is what the error message mentions. As you can see in my object models and the stored procedure result set schema, I only ever have references to `EnvelopeId`. My best guess is that when EF Core decided to make a shadow property, it couldn't use `EnvelopeId` since I already had it in my object model, so it created one called `EnvelopeId1` and then expected it to be present in the result set of the stored procedure.

Comment: `EnvelopeId1` vs `EnvelopeId` ?

Comment: EnvelopeId sounds like a pirmary key, so you will have some issue making it optional. Aside from that, you got the naming missmatch as tymtam pointed out.

Comment: @tymtam, this is not a typo. I do not have `EnvelopeId1` defined anywhere in my code or in the stored procedure result set, but `EnvelopeId1` is what the error message shows.

Comment: @Christopher, yes `EnvelopeId` is a primary key for a different object (`Envelope`) conceptually, but the way I have defined my `Recipient` object model, I only refer to it as a `Guid?` so it wouldn't be required. But your comment makes me think it may have something to do with the data type of `Guid?`. I tried something similar with a data type of `long` and the `[NotMapped]` attribute worked exactly as expected.

Comment: You need to post your schema for `Envelope` as well as a sample of the SP output. Just because you don't think a property is not required, doesn't mean that it isn't required. :)

Comment: Why is `Recipients` in `Envelope` marked as _not mapped_? Do you not want the ForeignKey constraint in the database? It looks like you may have created the database schema before you marked the `Recipients` as _not mapped_ and not changed the database schema since.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two reasons for this error message:

> The required column 'EnvelopeId1' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

The obvious one, for every column in the SQL result set, there must be a corresponding property in the object graph that you are trying to hydrate, in this case your `Recipient` class does not have `EnvelopeId1`.

Because your query is a stored procedure, it would be wise to post the SQL result in questions like this as it will show the SQL structure that you are trying to map to your object graph.

The reason that `EnvelopeId1` is in your SQL tables but not in your object graph is because the Entity Framework has created a [Shadow Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) for the [foreign that you have not defined a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#no-foreign-key-property) for.

You haven't listed the Schema for `Envelope` but my money says you have an equivalent `ICollection<Recipient>` property.

Creating a `NotMapped` property for `EnvelopeId` just makes this schema more confusing instead we should map it properly, or you should omit it from your Stored Procedure output.

> If you are going to use `FromSql` variants in EF (.Net or Core) then you should always define navigation properties in the schema classes as *Shadow* or *Auto* foreign key columns in the database will cause trouble unless you explicitly omit the columns that exist in the database but not in your schema
>
> > This means no `SELECT *` you will have to explicitly define all columns.

**Solution 1: Modify Stored Procedure**
You could simply modify your stored procedure to not return `EvelopeId1` from your recipient table.

**Solution 2: Fully define properties for both ends of all relationships in your data classes**
Here I have used `EnvelopeId1` as the name so that no migrations a needed, I would however recommend you change this to `EnvelopeId`, I personally use the existence of any field in the DB that ends in a numeral as an indication that some of my relationships have been inadequately defined.

```
public class Recipient
{
    [Key]
    public long RecipientId { get; set; }
    public Guid? EnvelopeId1 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(EnvelopeId1))]
    public virtual Envelope Envelope { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public int RoutingOrder { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StatusDate { get; set; }

    public Recipient() { }
}
```

This is based on the assumption that your Envelope class has a definition that is similar to this partial definition:

```
public class Envelope
{
    [Key]
    public Guid EnvelopeId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Recipient> Recipients { get; set; } = new Hashset<Recipient>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, [NotMapped] was the attribute I was looking for.